# Grep linux regex in html source

Tags: html, regex, linux, bash, grep

I have a source like this:

```
.more code
.more code
.more code
<textarea class="logarea" rows="15" name="log" spellcheck=FALSE>sometext
sometext
sometext
sometext
</textarea><br/><br/>
.more code
.more code
.more code
```

So, how to grep everything between
`'<textarea class="logarea" rows="15" name="log" spellcheck=FALSE>'` and `'</textarea><br/><br/>'` ?

Comment: Just [don't](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).

Comment: I have a bash code and I want to grep this text into variable, and save into file.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/<textarea class="logarea" rows="15" name="log" spellcheck=FALSE>sometext/,/<\/textarea><br\/><br\/>/ {print}' input
```

This produces the output:

```
<textarea class="logarea" rows="15" name="log" spellcheck=FALSE>sometext
sometext
sometext
sometext
</textarea><br/><br/>
```

To get only the text in between those lines but excluding both those lines:

```
$ awk '/<\/textarea><br\/><br\/>/{f=0} f{print} /<textarea class="logarea" rows="15" name="log" spellcheck=FALSE>sometext/{f=1}' input
sometext
sometext
sometext
```

Comment: Yes. I want only text between tags.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible through `pcregrep`,

```
$ pcregrep -M -o '(?s)<textarea class="logarea" rows="15" name="log" spellcheck=FALSE>\K.*?(?=\n<\/textarea><br\/><br\/>)' file
sometext
sometext
sometext
sometext
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Unix commands are line-oriented and not multiline-oriented. My workaround is this:

```
sed 's/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n' | grep -o '<textarea.*</textarea>' | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```